# Are movies with aircraft incidents not shown on planes?

Tags: aviation, movies, censorship

[CinemaSins](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYUQQgogVeQY8cMQamhHJcg) (a YouTube channel of movie critiques) often points out movies that 'instantly make themselves unavailable for in-flight viewing due to plane-crash sequence' (e.g. [their review of Fight Club](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCFmCMur7tQ#t=1m45s)).

Is this true; are there guidelines that major carriers follow for entertainment selection? Are depicted incidents with private craft (e.g. a Cessna) okay?

Comment: I've seen a documentary on the effects of counterfeit airliner parts on air plane security on a plane before, including reporting of the Concorde accident.

Comment: The economist J.K.Galbraith noted that airport bookstalls never sold his economic history book  ["The Great Crash, 1929"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Crash,_1929) even when they sold his other books

Comment: A bit offtopic but… I remember I made a long trip in a bus a few years ago (in Europe), and the whole topic of a projected movie was the crash of a bus in a tunnel. I thought at this time the movie was not very well chosen.

Comment: I suspect this is somewhat dated; the types of movies shown (and violence levels) seems to have broadened since passengers have their own screens and can self-censor what they see.

Comment: @Oddthinking Exactly. I can recall if I've seen a plane crash in a movie while on a plane, but certainly the gravity of the content in general is at all time highs.

Comment: @fredsbend: I feel sure I have seen such a movie on an individual screen, but can't recall the details. I can also recall seeing a Bruce Willis action movie about 25 years ago that the whole cabin could see that had so much of the violent parts edited out, the plot made no sense. I wondered why they hadn't just made a movie selection that didn't need to be butchered to get it to a G rating.

Comment: With the rise in individual seatback IFE I've noticed far more un-cut movies, at least on some airlines. I've watched unedited movies on the Qantas IFE that contained uncensored nudity and violence. But plane crashes specifically I can't say. I'm guessing this was much more of an issue during the period where everyone on the plane had to watch the same movie, or when there was no netflix-style choose-your-own IFE where everyone had to scroll through the same 5 IFE "channels"

Comment: About two months ago I watched Terminator Dark Fate while flying on an Emirates A380 - thats got more than one plane crash in it, and was uncut.

Comment: The above flight also offered “Flight” and “Sully” as options for inflight entertainment as well.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not aware of entire movies being rejected, but scenes can get deleted. This happened with "Rain Man". From [Uneasy Airlines Get Final Cut on 'Rain Man'](http://articles.latimes.com/1989-06-29/entertainment/ca-3726_1_airlines-plane-rain-man)

> Passengers on at least 15 different airlines have been treated to
>   Dustin Hoffman and Tom Cruise's Academy Award-winning road trip in
>   "Rain Man" since the beginning of June, but the crucial scene that
>   propels them on their highway odyssey in the first place has been
>   edited right out of the picture.
>
> ...
>
> "I think it's a key scene to the entire movie. That's why it's in
>   there," Levinson told the Associated Press. "Without that scene, it
>   comes down to this: You basically lose an enormous impact of the film.
>   That scene tells you that they, mechanically, are forced to drive
>   across country and, secondly, that Charlie can only push Raymond so
>   far because he knows what will happen."

And at least a passenger organisation (not an airline organisation) has guidelines about this. From [Curious cuts to in-flight films](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/travel/you-censored-what-curious-cuts-to-in-flight-films/story-e6frg8rf-1226127272232?nk=d999919ef538efbd880105086fa521fd)

> The Airline Passenger Experience Association sets out a quick
>   checklist of standards of what’s considered appropriate mid-air
>   viewing: “No airline crash scenes or references to airline disasters;
>   caution in depicting or referencing terrorism or; no nudity/sex
>   scenes; no profanity; no racist comments or denigrating references to
>   cultures, religions, or nationalities; caution in depicting violence,
>   drug and physical abuse.